# Stability criteria of a sytem

Tags: control-theory

I am totally a noob about this subject :D

Here is a system :

[image]

If the open loop transfer function is equal to "-1", the output "Vout(s)" goes to infinity. Nevertheless it is said that a system is unstable only if the the tranfer function "1 + the open loop transfer function" has at least one zero in the right half plane ? Why it would be stable if the zero is in the left right plane ?

Thank you very much and have a nice day ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will drop the $(s)$ just to simplify notation.

First, the statement "1 + the open loop transfer function" is not correct if you have a $\beta$ block at the bottom. Usually, the block diagram has $\beta(s) = 1$ and then this statement is true. If we let $H = \frac{N_H}{D_H}$, $G = \frac{N_G}{D_G}$, and $\beta = 1$, i.e., $N_{X}$ is the numerator of $X$ and $D_X$ is the denominator of $X$. Then, the close loop transfer function is,
\begin{align}
\frac{V_{out}}{V_{ref}} &= \frac{HG}{1+HG} \\
&= \frac{\frac{N_H}{D_H}\frac{N_G}{D_G}}{1+\frac{N_H}{D_H}\frac{N_G}{D_G}} \\
&= \frac{\frac{N_H N_G}{D_H D_G}}{\frac{D_{H}D_{G}+N_H N_G}{D_{H}D_{G}}} \\
&= \frac{N_H N_G}{D_{H}D_{G}+N_H N_G} \qquad(*)
\end{align}

The "1+open loop transfer funcion" $= 1+HG = \frac{D_{H}D_{G}+N_H N_G}{D_{H}D_{G}}$. Notice that the zeros of this transfer function is equal to the poles of the closed loop system, i.e., denominator of (*). If the a zero of $1+HG$ is in the open right half plane then the pole of $\frac{V_{out}}{V_{ref}}$ is in the open right half plane and the system is unstable. Similarly, if all the zeros of $1+HG$ are in the open left half plane then the poles of $\frac{V_{out}}{V_{ref}}$ are in the open left half plane and the system is stable.

Comment: Thank you ! This is interesting ! Actually this was not my question ... My questiion is more simple than this. It is often said that as the transfer function goes to infinity at its poles, so it is unstable. But nevertheless it follows the poles need to be in the RHP for being unstable. But it will be stable if there are in the LHP. So the argument as the the tranfer function goes to infinity has no sense ! Actually If take a look this afternoon and I see that if we use the inverse Laplace's transform, when we have a pole in the LHP, the exponential associated decays and grows up in the RHP

Comment: If you have a transfer function G and you do a partial fraction decomposition you will end up with $G(s) = \frac{a_1}{s + p_1} + \frac{a_2}{s + p_2} + \dots$ (Assuming the poles are real and not repeating for simplicity). Then the inverse Laplace transform for a term $\frac{a_i}{s + p_i}$ is $a_{i}e^{-p_i t}$. If $p_i < 0$ then it is expontially increasing and if $p_i > 0$ then it is expontially decreasing.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for !